# Visualization coordination on map

Tags: r

I have two dataframes as below:

dataframe pickup:

```
PickUP <- data.frame(pickuplong = c(-73.93909 ,-73.94189 ,-73.93754,-73.91638,-73.92792 ,-73.88634), pickuplat =c(40.84408,40.83841,40.85311,40.84966,40.86284,40.85628))
```

dataframe dropoff:

```
Dropoff <- data.frame(pickuplong = c(-73.93351 ,-73.93909 ,-73.93909 ,-73.80747,-73.95722,-73.91880), pickuplat =c(40.76621,40.84408,40.85311,40.69951,40.68877,40.75917), Droplong =c(-73.91300,-73.96259 ,-73.94870,-73.93860,-73.93633, -73.90690), Droplat =c(40.77777,40.77488 ,40.78493,40.84463,40.75977,40.77013))
```

I can find the coordinations in the drop off data frame which are similar to pickup like this:

```
 findcoord <-  subset(Dropoff, PickUP$Pickup_longitude %in% Dropoff$Pickup_longitude)
```

How can I visualize the records of Drop-off data frame on the map where the Dropoff data frame pickup longitude and latitude are similar to longitude and latitude PickUp data frame? [Visualization Expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9QBo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your example script of `findcoord`, the data frame was empty. So I do not fully understand what you want. The example script I show you below is a way to visualize the spatial point data using the `mapview` package. I took your `Dropoff` data frame as an example and create a html interactive map. It is likely you can follow the same strategy to plot your data once you have prepared your data frame.

If you don't want an interactive map, the `ggmap` package may fit your needs.

```
# Load packages
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)

# Create a column storing ID
Dropoff$ID <- 1:nrow(Dropoff) 

# Separate pickup and drop-off coordinates
Dropoff_p <- Dropoff[, c("ID", "pickuplong", "pickuplat")]
Dropoff_d <- Dropoff[, c("ID", "Droplong", "Droplat")]

# Create spatial point data frame for Dropoff_p and Dropoff_d
coordinates(Dropoff_p) <- ~pickuplong + pickuplat
coordinates(Dropoff_d) <- ~Droplong + Droplat

# Set the projection using WGS84, logitude and latitude
proj4string(Dropoff_p) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
proj4string(Dropoff_d) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")

# Visualize the data using mapview
map_p <- mapview(Dropoff_p, color = "red")
map_d <- mapview(Dropoff_d, color = "blue")

# See two maps together
map_p + map_d
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have few issues 1) The coordinations are in Newyork city area but the map shows Manhattan. 2) I want to show that how many of the coordinations (pickup longitude and latitude) in pickup data frame can be found in Dropoff data frame and also the location of them on the map.I draw one image in the post to give some visualization about the expected result.

Comment: I plot the points completely using the coordinates in the `Dropoff` data frame. If the map extent is not what you expected, perhaps you need to check your coordinates. And like I mentioned in my post, `findcoord` is empty, so I don't know how to work on the example you provided.

Comment: Actually, I double check the result. I believe it is correct.Thanks

Comment: if I want to do the same operation on 2 other different data frames with the similar format. How can I add them to the same map? thanks

Comment: After you create a mapview object, like map_p and map_d in my example, you can use plus sign to combine multiple maps and visualize them.